# Jquery click function exclude children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey I'm having an issue figuring this one out.

### JS

```
$('.jrm-menu-categories,#overlay-2').click(function() {
           $('#overlay-2').toggle();
           $('#overlay-3').hide();
});
```

### HTML

```
<ul id="megaUber" class="megaMenu">
    <li id="menu-item-1459" class="jrm-menu-categories">
        <ul class="sub-menu sub-menu-1">
```

So basically what my JS does is create an overlay/modal effect when a sub menu is opened via  click. I have the code repeated a few times with different classes and overlay ids hence the last line of code (needed so that only one overlay is shown at a time). Quickest and simplest way for a beginner like me, but that's not the subject.

When a sub-menu is open, and a user clicks anywhere in the sub-menu it toggles the overlay. I'm assuming this is because when I selected .jrm-menu-categories in the JS, it also selected the child elements, which happen to be .sub-menu

I'm thinking I need to use the .not() function, but can't figure it out.

can you guys help me with this? if possible write the code so I can try it out

Thanks!

Comment: for one thing you've got `<li>` and `<ul>` mixed up. Your HTML is not valid.

Comment: You can have a `<ul>` in an `<li>`

Comment: @StephenThomas perhaps the `<li>` is one of the menu items in a bigger `<ul>`, he didn't paste the complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding a second click handler to the children that will always return false. That way the click won't propagate up and dismiss:

```
$('.jrm-menu-categories').children('.sub-menu').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); // prevent click propagation, so parent click never fires.
})
```

Comment: Actually I just noticed that this breaks my links. I can't click on the links in the menus anymore

Comment: Try it with e.stopPropagation()

Comment: @John_911 `e.stopPropagation()` will let all event for the current item finish processing, but prevent parent events from firing. Using `return false` stops the events for the current object, as well as the parent events. I updated my solution accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can test for the clicked item.

```
$('.jrm-menu-categories,#overlay-2').click(function(e) {
    if (this == e.target){
           $('#overlay-2').toggle();
           $('#overlay-3').hide();
    }
});
```